# C program on Mac works unexpected

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, getchar

I have this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c;
    while(c != EOF){
        printf("Enter character\n");
        c = getchar();
        printf("Character: %c\n", c);
    }
    printf("FIN\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the terminal seems odd, because the while loop gets executed twice after a character was entered:

```
Enter character
a
Character: a                //This should be the last output after a char was entered, but the loop gets executed a second time without waiting for a keyboard-input:
Enter character
Character: 

Enter character
```

In the terminal I'm compiling and running the code like this:

```
gcc main.c
./a.out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the answers, It's the lf entered by enter .... It's so obvious :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entering 2 characters, the 'a' and a LF.

The while test is not made until both have been processed.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your program has undefined behavior because you are using uninitialized variable `c` in the condition of the while loop

```
int c;
while(c != EOF){
//...
```

The function `getchar` also reads white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` that is placed in the buffer after pressing the Enter key.

Another problem is that you are checking the variable `c` after reading and outputting it

```
while(c != EOF){
    printf("Enter character\n");
    c = getchar();
    printf("Character: %c\n", c);
}
```

Instead of `getchar` you should use `scanf` as for example

```
char c;

while ( scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1 )
{
    //...
}
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`. This blank means that white space characters will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm loosing so much basic knowledge since I have to program exclusively javascript for the last five years :(

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you press `enter`, a newline character gets added to the input stream. So your program actually reads two characters: `a` and `\n`. This newline character is read by `getchar()` and assigned to `c` in the second iteration and you can actually see it being printed as an empty line. Before printing `c`, you could use a `break` statement to get out of the loop: `if (c == '\n') break;`

If you enter `abc`, you will see the empty line is printed after `c`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's obvious when I read your answer.